# How to- group by a column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table as:

```
class   name
xxx     first
xxx     second
yyy     one
yyy     two 
yyy     three
```

I want to have the output as:

```
class    details
xxx      xxx first second
yyy      yyy one two three
```

So, the output should contain the class and also the concatenation of the class and name values.
How can I do this in hive since all the fields are String values?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collect_list()` and `group by` to get the list of name values for each class.Finally `concat` class and details to get the desired output

```
select class,concat(concat(class,' '),details) from 
(
    select class, collect_list(name) as details
    from table_name
    group BY class
)
```